# Django.Programming Error: Table Name Does Not Exist - How to solve?

Tags: django, django-models

I deleted a model in Django which I created for testing purposed. Now when I try and run makemigrations and mirgrate I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: table "members_test" does not exist
```

Is there a standard procedure I should be doing when deleting a model? I only deleteed the code out of my Models file and tried migrating after.

I've only tried runing migrate and make migrations in addtion to scouring the web.

Comment: Deleting the model's code does not delete the DB table. Did something go wrong when ran the subsequent migration? Or was the table dropped using SQL?

Comment: Forgot to drop the table. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can delete all migrations folder and re-migrate using below command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname
python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001
python manage.py migrate
```